# what is the best way for submitting form in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React.And I am trying to submit a form.There are two fields in my form.On referring the examples, I saw on `onChange` event corresponding state changed.I used `redux` for state management.My doubt is whether I call an `action` on `onChange` event.

Comment: you can use redux form and formsy to submit form...

Comment: @AshishChoudhary thanks for the reply. It does not need to call an action in each `onChange` event.Am I correct?

Comment: yesssssss......